# Refreshing page vs Other processes in the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using a Radgrid in my page. There is a Refresh button in the page to refresh the page to see changes done by other users. I have so many functional buttons in the page (e.g.: mail sending, assigning a row etc…).During other processes if I click refresh button, will it affect the current processes? Is there any chance of data mix up?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your code.You have to handle each and every process safely,so that it may not mix up with other process.

Comment: if i am doing a process with grid(eg:sending all rows as mail to some one) and clicked refresh button(refreshing the page will rebind the grid).Is this affect mail sending process?

Comment: If you have such doubts,then put your radgrid in update panel..so that page will not be refereshed,only your grid data is refreshed..

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing asynchronous calls, then you will have a very good chance of not mixing up data. The issue that might arise is that if you do this client-side via jQuery, then the async call might not make it back to the success/completed handler of the jQuery `.ajax()` function, especially if you navigate away from the page, but the server-side operation will continue its work.

You should send emails asynchronously when possible, using [SmtpClient.SendAsync Method (MailMessage, Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x5x13z6h.aspx).